# Geometrically, what does the linearity of an operator imply?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, functions, linear-transformations, intuition

In linear algebra, I learned that we define linearity as

**A map/mapping is linear if it preserved additivity and scaling.**

If you prefer symbols:

$L(\vec{\mathbf{v}})$ is linear if:

> $$ L(\vec{\mathbf{v}}_1) + L(\vec{\mathbf{v}}_2) = L(\vec{\mathbf{v}}_1 + \vec{\mathbf{v}}_2) $$
> $$ L(k\vec{\mathbf{v}}) = kL(\vec{\mathbf{v}})$$

Note: I kind of feel like linearity is one of the fundamental concepts of linear algebra as it’s literally in the name; it’s the algebra of linearity

This implies that mapping a sum of vectors is the same as summing up the mapped individual vectors for the additivity, and

Mapping a scaled vector is the same as scaling the mapped vector.

There are also other things which satisfy additivity and scaling.

A well-known example is the derivative operator $\frac{d}{dx}$, which is linear by the sum rule and constant multiple rule:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(f + g) = \frac{d}{dx}(f) + \frac{d}{dx}(g)$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}(kf) = k\frac{d}{dx}(f)$$

This means that in some sense, mapping a sum of functions is the same as summing up the mapped functions, and that

Mapping a scaled function is the same as scaling the mapped function.

Some other operators that do this are:

- The integral operator
- The Fourier transform operator
- The Laplace transform operator
- The convolution operator
- etc.

The thing that makes linear transformations different is that there is an enlightening geometric interpretation for the linearity of a map:

> A linear map $L(\vec{\mathbf{v}})$ is linear if the origin stays fixed and grid lines remain parallel and evenly spaced

If you wanted to get a little formal about the origin part, we can basically say that $L(0) = 0$, where $0$ is the zero vector. This means that a map has to map the origin to the origin to be linear.

**Question**: Is there any geometric intuition for the linearity of non-linear algebra-ish operators? Is there a thing as “mapping” every function in the space of infinitely differentiate functions to their corresponding derivative?

Any help or idea is appreciated!

This question is related to a question I asked previously: [What are some linear operators outside linear algebra or analysis?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4858080/1286095)

Comment: "A linear map is linear if the origin stays fixed and grid lines remain parallel and evenly spaced" - this is not true. An orthonormal basis is not necessarily mapped to an orthonormal basis.

Comment: @Filippo I  never said that an orthonormal basis is mapped to another orthonormal basis - that almost never happens unless the mapping is a rotation of space anyway.

The zero vector being mapped to the zero vector and lines staying parallel and evenly spaced is still a geometric property of linear transformations. Lines staying evenly spaced and parallel does not have much to do with the orthonormality of a basis.

Comment: "I never said that an orthonormal basis is mapped to another orthonormal basis" - I thought that this is what you mean by "lines staying parallel and evenly spaced". If not, then what exactly do you mean by this?

Comment: @Filippo There is a certain geometric intuition for linear transformations, where each input vector gets moved to its output vector (according to the mapping), transforming space. This is where the term “linear **transformation**” comes from. Now, a **linear** transformation is a transformation where the zero vector gets mapped to the zero vector  (the origin stays where it is) and grid lines remain parallel and evenly spaced (no lines get curved, as that would not preserve additivity and scaling). This is the geometric view often used to introduce mappings.

Comment: Oh I see, there is a nice Youtube video from 3Blue1Brown for illustration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A linear map  $F: V \to W$  from one  linear space $V$ to another linear space $W$ over the same field  is nothing more than  a statement of the formula $ F L x = L'  F  x$ , where L and L' are linear  endomorphisms of $V,W$ with the same coefficients.

The definition is so general, that its content is nearly emtpy.

Examples start with restriction  of a linear map to its kernel, mapped to null space, continues with linear 1-forms on finite dimesional vector spaces for determination of coordinates in a basis, matrix maps between finite dimensional spaces, multilinear maps between tensor products.

Its exploding  into an universe of linear functionals over linear subspaces of function spaces with values in abstract linear structures in functional analysis.